# Mysqli INSERT not showing in database and no errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, mysqli

I'm trying to insert this information into my database, I have practically the same code setup for SELECT queries and they work.  Any INSERT queries I try will not work.

This function returns true, and I've echoed the query this function creates and have used PHPMyAdmin to run the SQL query where it'll show in the database but when doing it through this php code the INSERT never shows up in the database.

**EDIT : I noticed that one of my columns (`orderID`) that is set to auto increment IS increasing every time I run this function but for whatever reason the query is not actually getting placed into the table.**

**[This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO8fZ.png) shows `orderID` of 29 is missing, I got those table results by doing 2 PHPMyAdmin INSERT queries, then one with the function and one more with PHPMyAdmin. Is there any way my function could be deleting the insert?**

```
function add_to_cart($user_id, $product_id, $quantity) {
global $mysqli;
    if($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO orders (userID, productID, quantity, orderDate) VALUES ('$user_id', '$product_id', '$quantity', NOW())")){
         return $result;
    }

return false;
}
```

The user connecting to the database has full privileges to the database so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: change the `return false` to `die($mysqli->error())` and see what pops up. you don't state HOW you handle the return values, so I'm assuming you're not checking for failure properly.

Comment: `global $mysqli;` do you really need that ?

Comment: If your `userID` column is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` chances are it won't work. If it is, remove `userID,` and `'$user_id',` Also check what the column `orderDate` is set to. Could be a number of things.

Comment: wild guess: are you commiting the transactions? (DML instructions affecting MyISAM tables are autocommited, but instructions affecting InnoDB tables can be commited later)

Comment: I need global because $mysqli isn't a local variable.  They're in separate php files. I put in die($mysqli->error()), it doesn't do anything.  The if statement returns true, which is why I was saying there isn't an error.

The column names aren't mispelled, as I said, I can echo out the query and paste it into phpmyadmin and the query runs fine.  None of the columns I have in the query are set to auto increment.

Comment: this autoincrement thing suggests a rolled back transaction.

Comment: Try this => `if($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO orders (userID, productID, quantity, orderDate) VALUES ('" . $user_id . "', '" . $product_id . "', '" . $quantity . "', NOW())")){` @ItsComcastic see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Fred-ii- variables in double quotes are parsed anyway, concatenation shouldn't be the issue here

Comment: Was worth a shot. The whole thing baffles me. The problem obviously lies elsewhere. @DamienPirsy

Comment: We shouldn't be here "taking shots", programming shouldn't be a "let's try something I know won't change anything, maybe it works". ...But I'm guilty of that too, I admit it :D

Comment: The line `$mysqli->commit();` fixed my issue, so @Barranka was right.  I'm not sure why I had to run that command, but that fixed the problem.

Comment: Because you have started a transaction somewhere. For some unknown reason. Better get rid of this start instead of adding commit

Comment: We're ALL guilty of something (or eventually) @DamienPirsy no one is spared, nor totally immune. ;-)

Comment: @Barranka, you say that instructions affecting InnoDB tables **can** be committed later.  What do you mean by that? (My tables are InnoDB)  All my queries are either SELECT or INSERT.  All the queries run without commit except the INSERT query.

Comment: @ItsComcastic InnoDB tables support transactions. That means that, unless the DML's (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) are commited, the data in the table won't be changed. If you want your instructions to be executed right away, enable autocommit in your connection: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php

Comment: @Barranka Ok, is there a reason the SELECT queries don't need commit? Reason I ask is because according to [orafaq.com](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands) SELECT is also a DML.  Does Mysqli just autocommit SELECT queries since they don't modify the database at all?

Comment: `SELECT` is (by itself) a read-only operation, so although it is a DML statement, it does not affect the data by itself; `SELECT` doesn't need to be commited because it does not change the data. But other DML statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`) do affect the data, and if they are used inside a transaction, they need to be commited to make the data changes persistent (of course, the changes can be rolled back too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by adding `$mysqli->commit();` after `$mysqli->query()`

I needed to do this because I changed the default options and had `"SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0"`

Taking that out allowed me to remove `$mysqli->commit()`

```
function add_to_cart($user_id, $product_id, $quantity) {
    global $mysqli;
    if($result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO orders (userID, productID, quantity, orderDate) VALUES ($user_id, $product_id, $quantity, NOW())")){
        if (!$mysqli->commit()) {
            print("Transaction commit failed\n");
        }
        return $result;
    }
    die($mysqli->error());
}
```

Comment: You have solved not the issue but consequence. I strongly suggests to find an operator or a setting that actually starts a transaction. Most likely you just copy-pasted it somewhere with other code.

Comment: I never turned on autocommit.  So if what Barranka said is correct,  I need to commit the INSERT query and it doesn't have anything to do with an open transaction.  I just checked all of my functions I only have this query making a change to the database.

Comment: You don't have to turn autocommit on. Because it's on by default. You rather shouldn't turn it off.

Comment: Looked at my Mysqli initialization code more closely.. Turns out I did turn autocommit off.  That's what I get for copying that block of code from online.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by other **numerous** questions of the same kind, you are just looking for the results in the wrong database.

Speaking of the function itself, it is bloated and unsafe.

You should use prepared statements.

```
function add_to_cart($user_id, $product_id, $quantity) {
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (userID, productID, quantity, orderDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
    $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(func_get_args());
}
```

there is no point in returning anything as in case of error an exception would be thrown. And even if  there was, still there is no use for a tautology like `IF result == true THEN return true ELSE return false`.  You can simply return the result itself.

Comment: Well I'm positive I'm looking at the right table for results. I'm checking them in PHPMyAdmin and the queries I entered in via PHPMyAdmin are showing up in `orders` I've updated my original post.  The queries aren't going into the database butone of the columns is auto-incrementing every time I try to run the query.

Comment: Well, debug your code. Community can do next to nothing with it. It could be a transaction or whatever. But it's only you who can find out

Comment: The whole reason I'm posting here is because I've debugged my code and have searched everywhere else.  I don't see anything wrong with my code and I haven't seen anyone else with my problem.

http://i.imgur.com/YYIgzk6.png The `orderID` of 29 is missing, I got those table results by doing 2 PHPMyAdmin INSERT queries, then one with the function and one more with PHPMyAdmin.  Is there any way my function could be deleting the insert?